# Does self.view has constraints?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, frame

self.view is on the ViewController. Does it have any constraints? I found it had a top and a left constraint. It has a frame for sure. The autolayout system starts from self.view. I mean until self.view the iOS system is still using frame for positioning the views. After that, our views are able to be added with autolayout. So in the viewcontroller, I use self.frame.size.width for the width constraint for my own view is the correct approach to do? Am I right?

Comment: The problem I am facing is that I have a customized view which will layout the buttons with different width line by line inside. If the horizontal space is not enough for placing the next button. It will be placed in the start of the next line. I am able to autolayout all the buttons if I know the width of my cusomized view. But I do this by using .frame which I don't like. I want to use something like widthConstraint.const or something else. I mean autolayout rather than frame. Sorry. Could not express what I want to say in the begining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SCREEN_WIDTH` and It's very easy to get your device size and manage your own view properly:

```
let SCREEN_WIDTH : CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let SCREEN_HEIGHT : CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
```

For more information you can refer this : [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller)

**Example :**
You should add your own new view programatically.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let SCREEN_WIDTH : CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let SCREEN_HEIGHT : CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

    let newView = UIView()
    newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    newView.frame.size = CGSize(width: SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.5 , height: SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.5)

    self.view.addSubview(newView)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
  }
}
```

Here I am giving the frame to the constraints of my customized view. I don't want to give this value in a format of frame.size. I want to use somethings like `constraint.constant`. I mean pure autolayout.
[image]

Comment: Sorry. I am trying to get rid of frame. I want to use constraints purely. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Michael Welcome but Still i can't understand what is actual problem so can you please post screenshot?

Comment: Hi, Anjali, I have uploaded the problem I am facing here.

Comment: Hello @Michael, Please change make.width.equalTo(self.view.size.width); to this line : make.width.equalTo(self.view);

Answer (score 0):

`self.view.frame` is only accurate once `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is called for the first time, typically just before `viewDidAppear` meaning if you try and access in `viewDidLoad` or first time `viewWillAppear` the frame will be wrong.

So you should just check in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` (but note that function is called whenever the layout changes (this does not mean you scroll on a table view, it means the actual constraints change bc of a screen rotation for ex, or otherwise)

If you can't wait until that method or have some code that's not idempotent and don't want to have some like `hasSetup` bool to make sure you only do it once... Then you can either access the screen size directly via `UIScreen.main.bounds`

OR

I wouldn't necessarily recommend the following but for the sake of completeness I've also gotten away with tricks to get the view to layout earlier like calling `view.layoutIfNeeded()` earlier in the view lifecycle or on the view controller that initializes:

```
let myVC = MyViewController()
_ = myVC.view // fixes frame for some reason
```

### Using AutoLayout correctly here

You want to use constraints but the frame shouldn't matter at all if you make relative constraints. Aka instead of saying `height = constant` you would say "make this the same height as vc.view" or "make the leading edge of this view 20 pixels right of the leading edge of vc.view".

something like:

```
    let myView = UIView()
    self.view.addSubview(myView)
    myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor)
    myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0) // 20 pixels to right of vc.view leading
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid these callbacks. I want to use somethings about constraints to do this...Thanks man anyway.

Comment: the frame can tell you what the constants should be for your constraints - but also....if you're using auto layout than the frame doesn't matter at all. add constraints using vc.view as a reference and when it finishes laying out all the constraints will update bc they're relative

Comment: So it think it's fine for what I did in the screenshot uploaded. I mean get the value from a frame when set the constant for the autolayout in viewController for the subviews of the self.view